# Github API: Unable to get list of members of an organization from code ... Although the same works from Postman

Tags: c#, .net-core, github-api

I am trying to fetch the list of members of any given organization on Github.com ... When I try it with Postman using the below Url and a Personal Access Token ... It works

"https://api.github.com/orgs/{orgname}/members"

But when I try it using my C# code with the same Url and Personal Access Token ... I get an empty Array instead ... What could I be missing? There are no errors since the HTTP Status Code is success ... But the Body of the response is an empty array like below:
"[]"

Comment: Are there any headers you're sending from Postman that you're not sending in the code?

Comment: I am sending the vital ones from code as well ... Like the Authorization, User-Agent one ... Calls to other end-points does work correctly with these

Comment: Try using a tool like Wireshark and compare the actual underlying requests from the two ways of sending it and determine the difference that way?

Comment: Just noticed something using Fiddler ... When I send a request from my code ... The rate-limit response header shows value of 60 ... Whereas in Postman the value is 5000!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After @Martin Costello comment above I used fiddler to analyze the two requests ... One sent using Postman and the other from my code ... It turns out that the way I was setting the Authorization header was incorrect ... This is how I was sending it earlier

```
_baseClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Authorization", authInfo);
```

Vs.

```
_baseClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authInfo);
```

The second approach works ... Feel kind of silly ... But thanks to @Martin Costello for the hint to analyze the requests using a Network traffic analyzer